# Changing subsubsection numbering without changing cleveref numbering

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I managed to change the subsubsection numbering with the following command :

`\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}.}`

However, the cleveref `\Cref{mysubsubsection}` return `Section 1.`

I would like to have a cleveref like `Section x.y.z.1`

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}.}
\usepackage[nameinlink, french]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\subsection{My subsection}
\subsubsection{My subsubsection}\label{mysubsubsection}
My section ref is : \Cref{mysubsubsection} and I would like to be "Section 1.1.1"
\end{document}
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}.}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for most cross-referencing packages since it updates the primary referencing components as well as the display component from the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection.}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{subsubsection}=0 .\fi% If this is a subsubsection, add a period
  \quad}
\makeatother

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{My Section}

\subsection{My subsection}

\subsubsection{My subsubsection}\label{sssec:mysubsubsection}

My section ref is : \Cref{sssec:mysubsubsection} and I would like to be ``Section 1.1.1''.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what this stuff is doing, but it's doing great ! Thx a lot !

Comment: Could you please post the same code for the paragraph ? :) It would be nice

Comment: @Maxouille: Try [this paste](https://pastebin.com/WUgc3zCj).

Comment: Thx ! One more question, is it possible to delete the dot after the full reference and keep it in the subsubsection numbering ? Like `1. my subsubsection` and `Section 1.1.1.1` ?